# Why 360 degree video is not working with SKVideoNode on iPhone 5 but it is working fine on iPhone 4s, 5s, 6 and 6 plus?

Tags: ios, iphone-5, iphone-6, 360-degrees, skvideonode

I am working with 360 video player with SKVideoNode. 
when i am playing video it is working fine on all devices except iphone 5. in iphone 5 video have black screen but audio is working. it is working on iphone 5 simulator also. Is there any device specific issue with my iPhone 5? because it working fine on 4s. Or issue with 360 degree video?

Answer (score 0):

without code its hard to say where is problem so I will guess -> you have some SCNView, SKVideoNode and maybe AVPlayer inside SKVideoNode or you are directly playing from SKVideo node basically controlling by AVPlayer should be working but first you have to set scene to playing by attribute scene.playing = YES;

If you are not using AVPlayer you can use SKVideoNode to play video like

```
scene.playing = YES;
[videoNode play];
```

This approach is working for me also on iPad mini with iOS 8, iPhone 5s ios 9 and iPhone 7 with iOS 10.

Problem is that SKVideoNode take all memory on iPhone 5s due to some memory leaks in SKVideoNode. I have already reported bug to Apple and waiting for response.